# Creating executable in Eclipse with VC compiler

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, cl

I'm trying to build my project and create an executable file in Eclipse using the Microsoft Visual C compiler. I get the following output in the Console:

```
12:02:42 **** Incremental Build of configuration Release for project ProjectName ****
make all 
Building target: ProjectName.exe
Invoking: Linker (link)
link /nologo /OUT:"ProjectName.exe"
link: cannot create link `/OUT:ProjectName.exe' to `/nologo': No such file or directory
make: *** [ProjectName.exe] Error 1
```

I have been searching for a solution for hours, but no result. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Looks like it's running cygwin's `link` instead of the VC linker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched to just using Visual Studio. Worked straight away.